# Using grep to search for '----i' returns error

Tags: shell, grep

I've been trying to find `'----i'` from a file. The file is a no-type text file with the following content:

```
-------------e-- ./login.defs
-------------e-- ./Public
-------------e-- ./lightdm.conf
----i--------e-- ./salad.sh
-------------e-- ./file4
-------------e-- ./Desktop
```

Using grep as follows:

```
grep -i '----i' filename
```

returns the following error:

```
grep: unrecognized option '----i'
```

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks!

Comment: I've edited your question so the file content is formatted as code. Please verify that it's still correct.

Comment: Use `grep -i -e '----i' filename` (Not posting an answer because this is probably a duplicate.)

Comment: You can use `grep -- '----i' file` as well.  `--` marks the end of all options (or switches).

Comment: Assuming this is `lsattr` content, it would be much more appropriate to use `grep -e '^[^[:space:]]*i'` -- after all, you're just looking for files that are immutable (thus, files which have an `i` anywhere in the flag block). With the code as it is, you're **excluding** files that have any of the other flags (before `i`) set, even if those files happen to also be immutable.

Answer (score 0):

The long and short of it is that you need to use `-e PATTERN` or `--regexp=PATTERN` if you want to use a pattern which may otherwise be treated as a `grep` option. So `grep -i -e '----i' filename` should do the trick.